# How to rennder a A tag inside a bulletlist Item Dynamically?

Tags: c#, html, stringbuilder

I have created a BulletList and i populate it dynamically using the following code.

```
HtmlGenericControl Link = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
Link.Attributes["href"] = "/ProductDetail/tabid/85/rvdsfpsq/" + Convert.ToString(row["Manufacturer"]) + "/default.aspx";
Link.Attributes["target"] = "_blank";
Link.InnerText = Convert.ToString(row["Manufacturer"]);

StringBuilder generatedHtml = new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(generatedHtml));
Link.RenderControl(htw);
string output = generatedHtml.ToString();
ListItem Item = new ListItem(output);

BulletList1.Items.add(Item);
```

The data populates fines from the Database. I can render the "a" tag perfectly. however the output is generated like below

```
<li> "<a href="/ProductDetail/tabid/85/rvdsfpsq/2-POWER/default.aspx" target="_blank">2-POWER</a>"</li>
```

What i need is

```
 <li><a href="/ProductDetail/tabid/85/rvdsfpsq/2-POWER/default.aspx" target="_blank">2-POWER</a></li>
```

So what change do i need to make to render the HTML without the "" qoutes???

Comment: add `.Trim(new char[{'"'}])` which remove the first and last quote from your hyperlink string

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlGenericControl Link = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
Link.Attributes.Add("href", "/ProductDetail/tabid/85/rvdsfpsq/" + Convert.ToString(row["Manufacturer"]) + "/default.aspx");
Link.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
Link.InnerText = Convert.ToString(row["Manufacturer"]);
//create ListItem as HtmlGenericControl.
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.Controls.Add(Link);
BulletList1.Items.add(li);
```

this will remove those quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work. The Only Items you can add to bUlletlist are listitems. You cannot add HtmlGeneric Controls

Comment: then I suggest to use DisplayMode="LinkButton" attr and onclick function call to handle the url.

Or

try to use listbox